# How to navigate deeper when only specified view (eg. title) is tapped on a row

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I have a view with a list. The list is a part of a navigation stack. When a row (`ArticleRow`) is tapped then user is redirected to a nested view (`ArticleContent`). I only want to navigate when the title is tapped not a subtitle.
I created `ArticleRow` view like this.

```
struct ArticleRow: View {
    let number: Int
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink("Title: \(number)") {
                ArticleContent(number: number)
            }
            Text("Subtitle: \(number)")
        }
    }
}
```

Despite the subtitle view is not part of the `NavigationLink`, tapping on the subtitle also causes navigation. How to solve that?

[image: Preview]

The code:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

extension Int: Identifiable {
    public var id: Int { self }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(Array(1...10)) { number in
                ArticleRow(number: number)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ArticleRow: View {
    let number: Int
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink("Title: \(number)") {
                ArticleContent(number: number)
            }
            Text("Subtitle: \(number)")
        }
    }
}

struct ArticleContent: View {
    let number: Int
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is article no: \(number)")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI `List` limits the ability to tap elements to the entire list unit (row) when a `Button` is nested inside that list row. `NavigationLink` is considered a button from the compiler's end, therefore that functionality will apply.

The only alternative I know of is taking advantage of `.onTapGesture { [...] }` and using a value-based `NavigationStack`.

Turn this:

```
NavigationStack {
    List {
        NavigationLink(value: "Destination") {
            Text("NavigationLink")
        }
    }
}
```

```
@State private var navigationValue = String()

NavigationStack {
    List {
        Text("NavigationLink")
            .onTapGesture {
                navigationValue = "Destination"
            }
    }
    .navigationDestination(for: navigationValue) { _ in
        Text($0)
    }
}
```